# nmcli question for ubuntu

Tags: nmcli

When I type in nmcli con it gives me a list of all previous connections, how do I delete these past connections it shows

```
 Nmcli delete cents --- doesn't work

 Nmcli --delete uuid --- doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax (at least for `nmcli` version 1.2.4) is

```
nmcli delete [id | uuid | path] ID...
```

i.e. the word `delete` (without leading `--`) followed by one of `id` or `uuid` or `path`, followed by the value of that field

e.g. given

```
$ nmcli con
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  9340c518-13a2-32c0-ae96-8790600dee2a  802-3-ethernet   --
```

then

```
$ nmcli con delete uuid 9340c518-13a2-32c0-ae96-8790600dee2a
Connection 'Wired connection 1' (9340c518-13a2-32c0-ae96-8790600dee2a) successfully deleted.
```